# Passing a Fabric env.hosts sting as a variable is not work in function

Tags: python, fabric, hosts, env

Passing a Fabric env.hosts sting as a variable is not work in function.

demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fabric.api import env, run

def deploy(hosts, command):
    print hosts
    env.hosts = hosts
    run(command)
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from demo import deploy

hosts = ['localhost']
command = 'hostname'
deploy(hosts, command)
```

python main.py

```
['localhost']
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

But env.host_string works!

demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fabric.api import env, run

def deploy(host, command):
  print host
  env.host_string = host
  run(command)
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from demo import deploy

host = 'localhost'
command = 'hostname'
deploy(host, command)
```

python main.py

```
localhost
[localhost] run: hostname
[localhost] out: heydevops-workspace
```

But the env.host_string is not enough for us, it's a single host.
Maybe we can use env.host_string within a loop, but that's not good.
Because we also want to set the concurrent tasks number and run them parallelly.

Now in ddep(my deployment engine), I only use MySQLdb to get the parameters then execute the fab command like:

```
os.system("fab -f service/%s.py -H %s -P -z %s %s" % (project,host,number,task))
```

This is a simple way but not good.
Because if I use the fab command, I can't catch the exceptions and failures of the results in Python, to make my ddep can "retry" the failed hosts.
If I use the "from demo import deploy", I can control and get them by some codes in Python.

So now "env.host " is the trouble. Can somebody give me a solution?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my insight.

According to [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/library.html), if you're calling fabric tasks from python scripts - you should use [fabric.tasks.execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute).

Should be smth like this:

- demo.py

  ```
  from fabric.api import run
  from fabric.tasks import execute


  def deploy(hosts, command):
      execute(execute_deploy, command=command, hosts=hosts)


  def execute_deploy(command):
      run(command)
  ```
- main.py

  ```
  from demo import deploy

  hosts = ['localhost']
  command = 'hostname'

  deploy(hosts, command)
  ```

Then, just run `python main.py`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander! I fixed it by myself, then found our ways are same.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally, I fixed this problem by using execute() and exec.**

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from demo import FabricSupport

hosts = ['localhost']

myfab = FabricSupport()
myfab.execute("df",hosts)
```

demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fabric.api import env, run, execute

class FabricSupport:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hostname(self):
        run("hostname")

    def df(self):
        run("df -h")

    def execute(self,task,hosts):
        get_task = "task = self.%s" % task
        exec get_task
        execute(task,hosts=hosts)
```

python main.py

```
[localhost] Executing task 'hostname'
[localhost] run: hostname
[localhost] out: heydevops-workspace
```